# How to translate a date object using angular-translate?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-translate

I have a list of date in my view, powered by my controller. I am using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) to manage localisation in my all application but do not know how to deal with date object.

My HTML looks like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="date in nextDates">
    <div class="day">{{date | date: 'EEEE'}}</div>
</div>
```

This code display a list a day : Monday, Tuesday, ... based on `date` which is a date object.

My first try was to use moment.js which is already used in this project, and deal really well with i18n. It works, but **I had a lot of difficulty to update it when lang is changed by user** since moment.js is not related to angular-translate.

I tried to implement it on my controller using an event to update my variable but didn't worked well. I would like to keep the object date in my view instead of having a moment object, I am sure there is a way not implementing it manually.

```
$scope.$on('translationChanged', function(event, lang) {
    ...
});
```

I would like to know if there is an easy way to solve this issue, my only idea is to generate a key for translation like `DAY.0` for Monday, `DAY.1` and translate it by myself but it sounds cheap. moment.js seems perfect for the job, but then how to link it with angular-translate ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so after some research I found a library on github called [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) which work fine for me.

First I import both js files + locale

```
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/locale/fr.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/locale/de.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/locale/it.js"></script>
```

Then I set up momentjs locale variable during my app mode config

```
var core = angular.module('app.core').config(configLang);

configLang.$inject = ['moment'];

/* @ngInject */
function configLang(moment) {
    moment.locale('en');
}
```

I then can start using in my templates amFormat directive directly on my Date object

```
<div ng-repeat="date in nextDates">
    <div class="day">{{date | amDateFormat:'dddd'}}</div>
</div>
```

If I want to change language in my app, I just use moment.locale(String); and my view is automatically updated.

```
$rootScope.$on('$authenticationStateChanged', function(event, userData, isAuthenticated) {
    moment.locale(userData.currentLanguage.toLowerCase());
});

$scope.$on('translationChanged', function(event, lang) {
    moment.locale(lang.toLowerCase());
});
```

I can then access all the power of moment.js in my angular app :D.