# How to translate the input text (datepicker) value dynamically using angular-translate?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate to provide i18n to my application, I am able to translate labels, button-text etc. properly.
The problem I am facing is when I am trying to change the date according to the selected language locale. The date is selected from a date-picker.

the date is selected into an input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" required="" ng-model="date" placeholder="{{ 'DATE_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}" translate="{{ 'select_date'|translate:{date:date} }}"/>
```

the placeholder translation works perfectly, but no change happens to date format when I change the language.
I have created a plunkr describing the current scenario.

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/1mTc7x)

**Please suggest a way in which I can translate inserted values, or text in forms. 
Also, I would like to know how to overcome the flicker of key values just before the page is loaded.**

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742365/how-to-translate-a-date-object-using-angular-translate)?

Comment: yes I have seen this, but this uses moment js and I will have to load all the locales just for the dates I am using, which I am not in favor of using

Comment: Here is a similar implementation in a directive http://jsfiddle.net/7y3y9nq7/   
Angular translate have some events; You can use it, for change model value  https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events

Comment: are you using ui-bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: @Angular_10 I am using https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add Italian locale, I copied it from http://forum.html.it/forum/showthread/t-2912577.html:

   ```
   $.fn.datepicker.dates['it'] = {
     days: ["Domenica", "Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato", "Domenica"],
     daysShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Gio", "Ven", "Sab", "Dom"],
     daysMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Gi", "Ve", "Sa", "Do"],
     months: ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"],
     monthsShort: ["Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"],
     today: "Oggi",
     clear: "Cancella",
     weekStart: 1,
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
   };
   ```
2. Add convert map for language codes from `en_EN` format to `en`:

   ```
   // language codes convertor map
   var convertorMap = {
     'en_US': 'en',
     'it_IT': 'it'
   };
   ```
3. In your language switcher function, remove current datepicker and initialize a new one with new language, make sure to update date in new format as well:

   ```
   $scope.switchLanguage = function (key) {
     var dp = $('#datePicker');
     // get current date
     var currentDate = dp.datepicker('getDate');

     // update datepicker with new locale
     dp.datepicker('remove');
     dp.datepicker({
       autoclose: true,
       language: convertorMap[key]
     });
     // restore current date according to the new locale
     dp.datepicker('update', currentDate);

     $translate.use(key);
   };
   ```
4. To show view only when translation is ready, change your wrapper element (I used `<body>`) to look like:

   ```
   <body ng-controller="Ctrl" class="ng-hide" ng-show="showView">
     .....
   </body>
   ```

   and in your controller:

   ```
   // will be fired when the service is "ready" to translate (i.e. loading 1st language)
   $translate.onReady(function () {
     $scope.showView = true;
   });
   ```
5. *ng-model* directive on jQuery datepicker does nothing, so I removed it, and added *ng-model* update code to initial datepicker function:

   ```
   $('#datePicker').datepicker({
     autoclose: true
   })
   // update ng model
   .on('changeDate', function(e) {
     $timeout(function () {
       $scope.date = $('#datePicker').datepicker('getUTCDate');
     });
   });
   ```

if you see in the console message like:

> pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization: No sanitization strategy has been configured. This can have serious security implications.

it is said to be fixed in next releases: https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-front/issues/778

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EGtHPG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for a beautiful and detailed solution 
For anyone who is using translatePartialLoader must refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123924/angular-translate-fouc-issues     to resolve issues related to flicker of untranslated text

Comment: Also please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247083/how-to-load-angular-translate-before-any-ui-is-displayed-with-ui-router-resolve                for resolving FOUC issue.